# List of elements in a model in .net core

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to understand how models work in .net core and I run into the following problem:
I have a model called blog:

```
public class Blog
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]
    [StringLength(40)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date is required")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Image is required")]
    public string Image { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required")]
    [StringLength(400)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Paragraph> Paragraphs { get; set; } = new List<Paragraph>();

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "IsActive is required")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public Blog(){}
}
```

And the paragraph model:

```
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Section is required")]
    public string Section { get; set;}

    [Required]
    public int? BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }

    public Paragraph()
    {
    }
```

And when executing the method that should bring me the data from this blog, it returns the list of empty paragraphs

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/[controller]/{id}")]
    public IActionResult GetById(int id)
    {
        var findBlog = _db.Blog.Find(id);
        if (findBlog == null)
        {
            return NotFound("Blog not found");
        }
        return new JsonResult(findBlog);
    }
```

The response:

```
{
"id": 6,
"title": "Test List",
"date": "2021-10-28T00:00:00",
"image": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2489/street-building-construction-industry.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500",
"description": "Desc",
"paragraphs": [],
"isActive": true,
"companyId": 1,
"company": null
}
```

Comment: I trust that the result you checked in controller that you get proper list, only conversion issue. There is 2 things I noticed. First try change `virtual IList<Paragraph>` to `List<Paragraph>` i.e. normal list. Second `var findBlog = _db.Blog.Find(id);` convert with `List<blog> findBlog` to get/check exact mapping

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me solve another problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `.Inclue()` to include the related data like below:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var findBlog = _db.Blog.Include(a => a.Paragraphs).First(a => a.Id == id);
// all these ways can work well
//var findBlog = _db.Blog.Include(a => a.Paragraphs).Where(a => a.Id == id).ToList();
//var findBlog = _db.Blog.Include(a => a.Paragraphs).FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
```

Reference:

[Eager Loading of Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager)

Comment: After the point the Include does not recognize me

Comment: I was not importing EntityFrameworkCore, I will run a test and I guess this should be my problem

Comment: Ok, you can test by using my code and I will wait for your response. If any issue, please follow up to let me know. If my answer helps you, remember to accept as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using Entity Framework Core. Then you need to [load related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/) using `include` function.

for an example

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
        .Include(blog => blog.Owner)
        .ToList();
}
```

for your case

```
 await _dbContext.Blogs
 .Include(blog => blog.Paragraphs)
 .FirstOrDefaultAsync(blog => blog.Id == id);
```

And to achieve this, you need to have proper relationships between entities.

See the SchoolContext [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager)

Comment: I am using .net core 3.1

Comment: Yeah, efcore should be there to execute database calls. It is handling database operation in .net core.